# A discontinuous almost everywhere map does not admit an invariant measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let's consider a map $T: X \rightarrow X$ so that it's discontinuous almost everywhere (in particular, let $X = \mathbb{R}$, and $T = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ -- Dirichlet function). Is it true that $T$ does not admit an invariant measure (e.g. $\lambda(X) = \lambda(T^{-1}(X))$)?

The original problem is to find a map from $3$-dimensional ball to itself with the given property. Bogolybov-Krylov theorem states that for every compact space $X$ and for every continuous $T$ such measure does exist. So, it's reasonable to look for a very "bad" maps, such as considered before.

Comment: Are you necessarily considering the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the 3-dimensional ball?

Comment: @JonathanY. I shall suppose that yes, since the Bogolybov-Krylov theorem works in this case and may not work (?) in others.

Comment: The Krylov–Bogolyubov th. only looks at Borel-measurable spaces (which are compact with the given metric), else continuity means very little. My next question would then be, are you only interested in the Euclidean metric on the (presumably closed) 3-dimensional ball?

Comment: @JonathanY I've gone through several proofs of the theorem -- from the space it's strongly required to be compact (in order to apply Banach-Alaouglu theorem or to apply Schauder fixed point theorem, where convexity is also needed, but not from the instant set). I suppose that it would be difficult enough to proceed in the case of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so it would be interesting to know how to approach in any case.

Answer (score 1):

In short: *Even if your function is discontinous almost everywhere, it still can possess an invariant measure.*

---

First of all, I belive that in order to pose your question correctly one needs a measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$, then one can ask if a measure $\lambda : \Sigma \to [0,\infty] $ exists with
$$ \lambda(A) = \lambda(T^{-1}(A)) $$
for all $A \in \Sigma$.

For the case that one has no requirements on $X$ and $\Sigma$ is not pre-definied, one can simply set $\Sigma := \{ \emptyset, X\}$  and define the measure $\lambda(\emptyset):=0$, $\lambda(X):=1$, this would be invariant for any function $T : X \to X$.

For the case where $X=\mathbb{R}$ is given with an $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ such that $T(x) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ is measurable, one can simply define the Dirac measure

$$ \lambda(A) = \begin{cases} 1,& \text{if }1 \in A, \\ 0,& \text{else}.\end{cases} $$

To see that this measure is invariant according to $T$, note that
$$ T^{-1}(A) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Q}, & 1 \in A, \, 0 \notin A, \\ \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}, & 1 \notin A, \, 0 \in A, \\ 
\mathbb{R},  & 1 \in A, \, 0 \in A, \\ \emptyset,  & 1 \notin A, \, 0 \notin A, \\    \end{cases} $$ and thus

$$ \lambda(T^{-1}(A)) = \begin{cases} 1, & 1 \in A, \, 0 \notin A, \\ 0, & 1 \notin A, \, 0 \in A, \\ 
1,  & 1 \in A, \, 0 \in A, \\ 0,  & 1 \notin A, \, 0 \notin A, \\    \end{cases} = \begin{cases} 1,& \text{if }1 \in A, \\ 0,& \text{else}.\end{cases} = \lambda(A). $$

The solution is intuitive: If you start in 1, then you remain there.

Answer (score 1):

Given a continuous map $T: X \to X$ where $X$ is compact and Hausdorff with no isolated points, and a  countable dense subset $S$ of $X$, you can make $T$ continuous nowhere by changing $T$ on $S$.  Divide $S$ into two disjoint subsets $S_1, S_2$ that each are dense in $X$.  Choose two distinct points $p, q \in X \backslash S$, and 
define
$$ \widetilde{T}(x) = \cases{ T(x)& if  $x \notin S$\cr p & if $x \in S_1$\cr q & if $x \in S_2$}$$
 Any nonatomic measure that is invariant for $T$ is still invariant for $\widetilde{T}$, because $\widetilde{T}^{-1}(A)$ and $T^{-1}(A)$ differ at most on a countable set.

If $T$ has an invariant measure $\lambda$ that is not nonatomic, you can ensure it is still invariant for $\widetilde{T}$ by choosing $S$, $p$, $q$ so that 
$\lambda(S \cup \{p,q\}) = 0$.